# Filter a CSV by boole condition in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I am importing a CSV into python and adding a boole condition , I want to display rows that have a boole condition true only, Can someone please point me in the right direction

Comment: direction: pandas documentation

Comment: put at least the data so we can help you

Comment: better show some example code to show problem. I hope you don't have so basic problem which can resolve `print( df[ df == some_condition ] )`

Comment: What have you tried? This is like Pandas 101.

Answer (score 0):

Like furas says, just use `df[ df == some_condition ]`

e.g.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({'A':[1,2,3,4,5],'B':[True,False,True,False,False]})

print(df)

#filter for true
df = df[df['B']==True]

print(df)
```